# Getting link.exe, lib.exe, editbin.exe and dumpbin.exe to use the symbol server

Tags: debug-symbols, pdb-files, dumpbin

I have WinDbg set to download symbols to *c:\symbols*. The symbols for advapi32 (for example) are in `c:\symbols\advapi32.pdb\3F32049F550C42B09CF114A1FB8A97E92\advapi32.pdb`. The only way I've gotten link.exe, and those other stub exe's to use those symbols is to actually be in the directory `c:\symbols\advapi32.pdb\3F32049F550C42B09CF114A1FB8A97E92`. So for example `dumpbin /exports c:\Windows\SysWOW64\advapi32.dll` returns decorated names in that folder like so:

```
   1770  301 000455C6 UnregisterIdleTask = _UnregisterIdleTask@12
   1771  302          UnregisterTraceGuids (forwarded to ntdll.EtwUnregisterTraceGuids)
   1772  303 000595D8 UpdateTraceA = _UpdateTraceA@16
   1773  304 000595F9 UpdateTraceW = _UpdateTraceW@16
   1774  305 00042BB6 UsePinForEncryptedFilesA = _UsePinForEncryptedFilesA@12
   1775  306 00042BFF UsePinForEncryptedFilesW = _UsePinForEncryptedFilesW@12
```

And when run from another folder it returns:

```
   1770  301 000455C6 UnregisterIdleTask
   1771  302          UnregisterTraceGuids (forwarded to ntdll.EtwUnregisterTraceGuids)
   1772  303 000595D8 UpdateTraceA
   1773  304 000595F9 UpdateTraceW
   1774  305 00042BB6 UsePinForEncryptedFilesA
   1775  306 00042BFF UsePinForEncryptedFilesW
```

Is it possible to get dumpbin to use the dlls downloaded by the symbol server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer on the [msdn page for symbol paths](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff558829%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

That page states that the windows debuggers get their symbol list from three places:

- A runtime list set through the windbg menu and the [.sympath command](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff565407%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) e.g. `.sympath srv*c:\MyServerSymbols*http://msdl.microsoft.com/download/symbols`
- **_NT_ALT_SYMBOL_PATH** environment variable
- **_NT_SYMBOL_PATH** environment variable

So simply calling `SET _NT_SYMBOL_PATH=symsrv*symsrv.dll*c:\symbols2*http://msdl.microsoft.com/download/symbols` or adding that value to your permanent environment (e.g. through [setx](http://ss64.com/nt/setx.html)) will cause the symbols to load.